# Importing package.json in typescript file: 'require' call may be converted to an import

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm setting up a class whereby I'm directly importing the package version number into the class as follows:

```js
const pkg = require('../package.json')

export class MyClass() {
    constructor() {
        // Set the base version from package.json:
        this.version = pkg.version
    }
}
```

However, I'm currently getting a little friendly warning from the Typescript ghost in the machine saying that "'require' call may be converted to an import."

I'm assuming that yes it may be possible, but not with a .json file?

Perhaps I should be asking what the best practise for importing a package.json in a .ts file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable `resolveJsonModule` (see [TSConfig Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#resolveJsonModule)) in the `compilerOptions` of your tsconfig.json and then use an import.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "resolveJsonModule" : true,
  }
}
```

**myclass.ts**

```
import {version} from ('../package.json');

export class MyClass() {
  version: string;

  constructor() {
    this.version = version
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, nope - unfortunately this throws an error. probably because I didn't provide my tsconfig.json file => "'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files." My root directory is /src, package.json is one up from this. Is there a way to resolve this error in the compilerOptions?

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts Have you tried `"baseUrl": "./src",` in your `compilerOptions` instead of `rootDir`?

Comment: Yes, with this everything seems to be working as expected! Ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `import`.

```js
import pkg from './package.json';

export default class MyClass {
    public version: string;
    constructor() {
        this.version = pkg.version;
    }
}
```

Just a reminder when you import a module you are making your class dependent on that actual file I'd suggest you to inject the pkg by passing it to constructor.

Comment: Nope this doesn't work unfortunately, import { version } from './package.json'; -> "Cannot find module './package.json' or its corresponding type declarations."

Comment: You should add "resolveJsonModule":true as part of compilerOptions to tsconfig.json.

Comment: Yeh, it is set to true by default unfortunately.